# PHP Multidimensional Array to JSON Array of Objects

Tags: php, arrays, angularjs, json, multidimensional-array

The `ng-google-charts`.`bar-chart`([Refer here](http://angular-google-chart.github.io/angular-google-chart/docs/latest/examples/multi-chart/)) module accepts data in the following format:

```
var chartData = 
[
  {
    "c": [ // First bar
      { "v": "Thing A" }, // c_name
      { "v": 6 }, // # of c_assigned - c_completed
      { "v": "red"}, // color of a portion of bar
      { "v": 28 }, // # of c_completed
      { "v": "green"} // color of a portion of bar
    ]
  },
  {
    "c": [ // Second bar
      { "v": "Thing B" },
      { "v": 4 },
      { "v": "red"},
      { "v": 30 },
      { "v": "green"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "c": [ // Third bar
      { "v": "Thing C" },
      { "v": 12 },
      { "v": "red"},
      { "v": 21 },
      { "v": "green"}
    ]
  }
];
```

And the `print_r($data)` of my PHP is:

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
    (
      [c_name] => Thing A
      [c_assigned] => 34
      [c_completed] => 28
    )
  [1] => Array
    (
      [c_name] => Thing B
      [c_assigned] => 34
      [c_completed] => 30
    )
  [2] => Array
    (
      [c_name] => Thing C
      [c_assigned] => 33
      [c_completed] => 21
    )
)
```

Now the `json_encode($data)` results to this:

```
[
  {
    "c_name":"Thing A",
    "c_assigned":"34",
    "c_completed":"28"
  },
  {
    "c_name":"Thign B",
    "c_assigned":"34",
    "c_completed":"30"
  },
  {
    "c_name":"Thing C",
    "c_assigned":"33",
    "c_completed":"21"
  }
]
```

And the `json_encode($data, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT)` is this:

```
{
  "0":
    {
      "c_name":"Thing A",
      "c_assigned":"34",
      "c_completed":"28"
    },
  "1":
    {
      "c_name":"Thign B",
      "c_assigned":"34",
      "c_completed":"30"
    },
  "2":
    {
      "c_name":"Thing C",     
      "c_assigned":"33",
      "c_completed":"21"
    }
}
```

I use `$http` in getting the data:

```
function getThings(a,b){
  $http({
  method: "POST",
  data: $.param({a:a,b:b}),
  url: BASE_URL+"Conroller/Function",
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
  }).success(function(data){
    $scope.things = data;
  });
}
```

I'm very new to JSON. How can I make the data from php to be like the format needed by the module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could alter your $data as follows:

```
$data = array_map(function ($el) {
    return array(
        "c" => array(
            array("v" => $el['c_name']),
            array("v" => $el['c_assigned']),
            array("v" => 'red'),
            array("v" => $el['c_completed']),
            array("v" => 'green'),
        )
    );
}, $data);
```

Then, generate the JSON as follows:

```
$json = json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

This will have as value:

```
[
    {
        "c": [
            {
                "v": "Thing A"
            },
            {
                "v": 34
            },
            {
                "v": "red"
            },
            {
                "v": 28
            },
            {
                "v": "green"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "c": [
            {
                "v": "Thing B"
            },
            {
                "v": 34
            },
            {
                "v": "red"
            },
            {
                "v": 30
            },
            {
                "v": "green"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "c": [
            {
                "v": "Thing C"
            },
            {
                "v": 33
            },
            {
                "v": "red"
            },
            {
                "v": 21
            },
            {
                "v": "green"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

<kbd>[Demo on eval.in](https://eval.in/567030)</kbd>